# Different Screen Size

Tags: java, android

Hey guys i just wanna ask When ever we display a background picture in our activity we placed the picture in the drawable folder with sub different folder like

```
drawable layout_hdpi or layout_mdpi or layout_ldpi or layout_xhdpi
```

and there is a specific density and dimension for each folder so that it can support multiple devices etc .

i want to ask that do i need to modify my picture for each folder like if my picture dimension is 3000*3000

first i have to modify it to 720*1280 for xhdpi and then put it in layout_xhdpi folder then i modify it for hdpi i.e 400*800 dimension and so on ..
It will take much time to do .Is There is any other easy method 
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the image for each size. Keeping it to a standard size(eg-1920*1080) would do the work for most of the phones. However for phablets or tablets, you would have to modify the image. Also reduce the images from 3000*3000 to a smaller size as this would increase the app size drastically, would be useless and might cause PNG crunching to fail.